# Using emberjs query parameters with a subroute 'transitionTo'?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to 'transitionTo' a sub-route of the current route and the seems to be ignored - there's no error it just doesn't happen.

**router.js**

```
this.route('produce', function() {
    this.route('download-form');
    this.route('download-form-new', {path: '/:prlid_for_form/:prrefnum_for_form/download-form'});   
});
```

**routes/produce**

From the 'produce' route this works as you would expect,

```
this.transitionTo('produce.download-form');
```

... that is the current route becomes 'produce/download-form', ...but if I replace that with this ...

```
 this.transitionTo('produce.download-form-new', { queryParams: { prlid_for_form: "99", prrefnum_for_form: 'ABC'} });
```

... it gets executed without error but no transition takes place.

This is in Ember 3.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `router` part looks good. However, there is a small issue in invoking the `transtionTo` API. The two entities `prlid_for_form` and `prrefnum_for_form` are **not query params but they are [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments).** Thus the `transitionTo` API should be invoked as follow:

```js
 this.transitionTo('produce.download-form-new', 99, 'ABC');
```

So, the value `99` will be mapped to the first dynamic segment, `prlid_for_form` and the later value, `ABC`, will be mapped to `prrefnum_for_form`.

For more details, refer the API docs of [`transitionTo`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your suggestion worked fine. I had read the doco but not well enough ;-)